# JPA QueryDSL exists and count

Tags: java, sql, jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to got these SQL-Statement to a QueryDSL call.

```
   select t.asd_id, count(*) as count from asset_object t 
     left join asset_data ad on (t.asd_id = ad.asd_id)
     where
       exists (select * from assetobject_parents p 
               where t.aso_id = p.aso_id and p.ctd_id = 1)
     group by t.asd_id
     order by count(*) desc, t.asd_id asc
```

Can anyone give me a hint or a solution?

Here is my Domain (extract):

```
@Entity
public class AssetObject {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ASO_ID")
    private Long asoId;


    @ManyToMany
    @OrderColumn(name = "ASP_ORDER")
    @JoinTable(name = "ASSETOBJECT_PARENTS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ASO_ID", referencedColumnName="ASO_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CTD_ID", referencedColumnName="CTD_ID") })
    private List<CategoryData> parents = new ArrayList<CategoryData>();

}

@Entity
public class CategoryData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CTD_ID")
    private Long ctdId;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSET_DATA")
public class AssetData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ASD_ID")
    private Long asdId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ASSETDATA_CATEGORYDATA", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ASD_ID", referencedColumnName="ASD_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CTD_ID", referencedColumnName="CTD_ID") })
    private List<CategoryData> categoryDataList = new ArrayList<CategoryData>();

}
```

Hope this helps a little bit more. I think the main point is that it's not possible to access join-tables with querydsl.

Comment: Did you try to do it yourself? Where are you struck?

Comment: Yes I've tried it. But I failed on many points: exists on assetobject_parents -> this is a connection-table from a many to many relation, select an id and count from one table, ...

Answer (score 7):

Here is a sketch for a solution

```
QAssetobject t = QAssetobject.assetobject;
QAssetData ad = QAssetData.assetData;
QAssetobjectParents p = QAssetobjectParents.assetobjectParents;

List<Tuple> results = query.from(t)
  .leftJoin(ad).on(t.asdId.eq(ad.asdId))
  .where(new SQLSubQuery().from(p)
         .where(t.asoId.eq(p.asoId), p.ctdId.eq(1)).exists())
  .groupBy(t.asdId)
  .orderBy(Wildcard.count.desc(), t.asdId.asc())
  .list(t.asdId, Wildcard.count);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't have a QAssetobjectParents class. This is only a many to many join-table. I think that's the problem.

Comment: Ok, I will provide also a JPA solution

Comment: Actually for the JPA solution I need more info about your domain. e.g. How does AssetobjectParents looks like as an entity?

Comment: Is it possible to use a join-table in querydsl?

Comment: Added an extract of my domain.

Comment: In QueryDSL 4 use `JPAQuery` instead of `SQLSubQuery`